# Loading new resource in same window

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently migrating all my .form files over to .fxml and I'm having a bit trouble loading another page within the same window.

With .form method I was able to establish a card layout and switch it within that.

What I would do is create a card layout and have the forms load in there.

I created a few test .fxml and some basic code. It loads the second one but in a new window and I'm trying to avoid that and load it within the same window.

index.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Test">
   <children>
      <Button id="btnbuy" fx:id="btnbuy" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadSecondFxml" text="Purchase" />
      <Button id="btnSell" fx:id="btnsell" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="454.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sell" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

MainPage.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Test">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="6.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="320.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="146.0" layoutY="232.0" text="You got here" />
         </children></Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Test.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    private MainPage parentForm;
    //private Panel panel;
    public Button btnbuy;
    public Button btnsell;

    public Test(){
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Index.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 320, 480));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public void loadSecondFxml() throws Exception{
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainPage.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hi");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 320, 480));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the setscene portion. But I'm having trouble trying to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Which one works best for you depends on your needs:

### Replacing the root

By replacing the root you can replace all the contents shown in a window.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Region r1 = new Region();
    r1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

    final Region r2 = new Region();
    r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    final Scene scene = new Scene(r1);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        scene.setRoot(scene.getRoot() == r1 ? r2 : r1); // swap roots
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

### Modifying part of the scene

By modifying a parent in the scene you can change the display.

#### `BorderPane`

This layout allows you to easily replace it's (up to) 5 nodes:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Region r1 = new Region();
    r1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

    final Region r2 = new Region();
    r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane(r1);

    Button btn = new Button("swap");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        root.setCenter(root.getCenter() == r1 ? r2 : r1);
    });

    root.setTop(btn);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### Modifying the child list of some other layout

This can be a bit more complex than using `BorderPane`, but `Pane`s and `Group` allow you to modify the `children` list to modify the layout:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Region r1 = new Region();
    r1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
    VBox.setVgrow(r1, Priority.ALWAYS);

    final Region r2 = new Region();
    r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
    VBox.setVgrow(r2, Priority.ALWAYS);

    final VBox root = new VBox();

    Button btn = new Button("swap");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        root.getChildren().set(1, root.getChildren().get(1) == r1 ? r2 : r1);
    });

    root.getChildren().addAll(btn, r1);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

Something like `TabPane` may also suit your needs.

Using something like this with fxmls requires you to provide access to the object managing the replacement. You can read about this topic here: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

You shouldn't use the `Application` class as controller class though. This violates the single responsibility principle. Also you create a new instance of the class every time a fxml with the class specified as value of the `fx:controller` attribute is loaded. The `Application` class is supposed to be the "entry point" of your program.